Optimizing a containerized database initialization and startup
I have a small Docker container running a static (read-only) database which contains data for drop-down menus and web ui content such as counties per state, zip codes, etc.
The image is generated whenever the database content is changed via a commit pipeline.  Currently, the database tables are populated when the container first starts using SQL scripts I created in docker-entrypoint-initdb.
So far, this is working well.  However, there is a container startup cost associated with running the initdb scripts and I am considering starting the container as part of the pipeline and then creating an image from the container once the database tables are populated.
Is this a container anti-pattern?   It feels a little unnatural from a pipeline/container perspective but it would allow containers to spin up faster.
I strongly prefer not to use a volume for this application as it really isn’t needed and it adds complexity to the deployed application.
